# Particles.js not working properly in .NET Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, particles.js

NET MVC Core and I am trying to use Particles.js. I have already tried referencing a few tutorials, but am unable to solve this issue. This is how it normally looks like. https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/#default

I got this however, with big and super laggy buttons and also it does not occupy full screen nor does it have the hover action (whereby the circle moves away as the mouse approaches). The onclick circle works though. And the configuration shouldn't be wrong, as I downloaded the default one.

Update: Just before posting I managed to make it full screen. However, the big buttons and lagginess remains.

[image]

The following is my codes so far. I tried to search the id or class but due to the lack of documentation it is quite hard to find. Hope someone who knows it can help! Thank you very much :)

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div id="particles-js" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-image: url(&quot;&quot;); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; ba">
    <canvas class="particles-js-canvas-el" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="~/js/particles.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload" asp-append-version="true"></script>


<script>
    particlesJS("particles-js", {
        particles: {
            number: {
                value: 400,
                density: {
                    enable: true,
                    value_area: 800
                }
            },
            color: {
                value: '#fff'
            },
            shape: {
                type: 'circle',
                stroke: {
                    width: 0,
                    color: '#ff0000'
                },
                polygon: {
                    nb_sides: 5
                },
                image: {
                    src: '',
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100
                }
            },
            opacity: {
                value: 1,
                random: false,
                anim: {
                    enable: false,
                    speed: 2,
                    opacity_min: 0,
                    sync: false
                }
            },
            size: {
                value: 20,
                random: false,
                anim: {
                    enable: false,
                    speed: 20,
                    size_min: 0,
                    sync: false
                }
            },
            line_linked: {
                enable: true,
                distance: 100,
                color: '#fff',
                opacity: 1,
                width: 1
            },
            move: {
                enable: true,
                speed: 2,
                direction: 'none',
                random: false,
                straight: false,
                out_mode: 'out',
                bounce: false,
                attract: {
                    enable: false,
                    rotateX: 3000,
                    rotateY: 3000
                }
            },
            array: []
        },
        interactivity: {
            detect_on: 'canvas',
            events: {
                onhover: {
                    enable: true,
                    mode: 'grab'
                },
                onclick: {
                    enable: true,
                    mode: 'push'
                },
                resize: true
            },
            modes: {
                grab: {
                    distance: 100,
                    line_linked: {
                        opacity: 1
                    }
                },
                bubble: {
                    distance: 200,
                    size: 80,
                    duration: 0.4
                },
                repulse: {
                    distance: 200,
                    duration: 0.4
                },
                push: {
                    particles_nb: 4
                },
                remove: {
                    particles_nb: 2
                }
            },
            mouse: {}
        },
        retina_detect: false,
    });
    //var count_particles, stats, update;
    //stats = new Stats;
    //stats.setMode(0);
    //stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    //stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
    //stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
    //document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);
    //count_particles = document.querySelector('.js-count-particles');
    //update = function () {
    //    stats.begin();
    //    stats.end();
    //    if (window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles && window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array) {
    //        count_particles.innerText = window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array.length;
    //    }
    //    requestAnimationFrame(update);
    //};
    //requestAnimationFrame(update);;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I finally found the answer. To facilitate people who working on this in the future, make sure to use the download from the sidebar and not the one in the center.

Not this (the download in the center):
[image]

But this (the one at the bottom right side, "Download current config(json)"):

[image]